# Мы разрабатываем сайты, которые пользователи не хотят покидать, уже 4 года. Нужна запятая после покидать?

Tags: запятые, спп

Мы разрабатываем сайты, которые пользователи не хотят покидать, уже 4 года. нужно ставить запятую перед "уже 4 года"? каким правилом обьясняется?

Comment: Так это... От смысла зависит. "Четыре года не хотят покидать" или "четыре года разрабатываем"?

Answer (score 3):

Это зависит от того, 4 года не хотят покидать (тогда запятая не нужна - первая запятая просто отделяет придаточное предложение от главного) или 4 года разрабатываете. Во втором случае запятая нужна (для обособления придаточного предложения внутри главного), но лучше сказать "мы уже 4 года разрабатываем..." - так яснее.